# Why can we not use move semantics only apply for pass-by-value and not const lvalue reference?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, rvalue

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140113221447/http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/#fn:named) is the article I am using as a reference, which was ultimately mentioned in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom).

The author gives two examples:

Example 1:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> 
sorted(std::vector<std::string> names)
{
    std::sort(names);
    return names;
}

// names is an lvalue; a copy is required so we don't modify names
std::vector<std::string> sorted_names1 = sorted( names );

// get_names() is an rvalue expression; we can omit the copy!
std::vector<std::string> sorted_names2 = sorted( get_names() );
```

Example 2:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> 
sorted2(std::vector<std::string> const& names) // names passed by reference
{
    std::vector<std::string> r(names);        // and explicitly copied
    std::sort(r);
    return r;
}
```

Then saying:

> Although sorted and sorted2 seem at first to be identical, there could
>   be a huge performance difference if a compiler does copy elision. Even
>   if the actual argument to sorted2 is an rvalue, the source of the
>   copy, names, is an lvalue, so the copy can’t be optimized away. In a
>   sense, copy elision is a victim of the separate compilation model:
>   inside the body of sorted2, there’s no information about whether the
>   actual argument to the function is an rvalue; outside, at the call
>   site, there’s no indication that a copy of the argument will
>   eventually be made.

My question is simple:
Why cannot the compiler use copy elision in the second example, but it can in the first?

What about passing by value and reference differentiates them? `names` is named in both instances, so I would assume we also create an lvalue in both instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that `names` modifiable object or not. const lvalue reference is not modifiable.

---

> since get_names() is a rvalue, we can use move semantics.

Not always. Consider when the move constructor is called.

> However if the parameter is a const lvalue reference, then we must "preserve" the value as an lvalue, so a simple switch of pointers cannot occur

When the parameter is lvalue reference, you can modify the object. However, you cannot pass an rvalue.

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> 
sorted3(std::vector<std::string>& names)
{
    std::sort(names);
    return names;
}

// names is an lvalue; lvalue reference can bind lvalue. argument will be modified after execution `sorted3`.
std::vector<std::string> sorted_names1 = sorted3( names );

// get_names() is an rvalue expression; we cannot bind by lvalue reference.
//std::vector<std::string> sorted_names2 = sorted3( get_names() );
```

const lvalue reference can bind rvalue. However, you cannot modify the object so that a simple switch of pointers cannot occur.

Comment: So if we consider `vector<string> names = sorted( get_names () )`, since `get_names()` is a rvalue, we can use move semantics. However if the parameter 
 is a `const` lvalue reference, then we must "preserve" the rvalue as an lvalue, so a simple switch of pointers cannot occur, correct? But when we pass-by-value, then no preservation is needed, correct? Sorry, I'm pretty new to this so some detail would make things clearer.